# select distinct values and count before distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

table1:

```
pid   fid     year      
1     a       1990
1     a       2002
1     a       2005
3     b       2000
3     b       2002
3     c       1999
```

i want the result to be :

```
  pid  fid  count
    1    a     3
    3    b     2
    3    c     1
```

itried

```
select distinct(fid), pid , count(pid)
from table1
```

any help please
thanks.

Comment: For a specific fid, does pid always same? E.g, when fid = a, is pid always equals 1?

Comment: yes fid cannot take more than 1 pid,but pid can take more than fid

Answer (score 2):

```
select pid, fid, count(*)
from table1
group by pid, fid
```